# Javascript Create Element in Two Divisions

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, appendchild, createelement

I want to create an iframe using javascript and then insert it into two divisions both having id "fblike". I tried to use the following code but it did not work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function(){
    var fb = document.createElement('iframe');
    fb.src = 'http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href='+encodeURIComponent(location.href)+'&amp;locale=en_US&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=90&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font=verdana&amp;height=21';
    fb.scrolling = 'no';
    fb.frameborder = '0';
    fb.style = 'border:none; overflow:hidden; width:90px; height:21px;';
    fb.allowTransparency = 'none';
    document.getElementsById('fblike')[0].appendChild(fb);
  })();
</script>
```

I know there must be some mistake(s) in the code because I have very little knowledge of javascript. Any one please help me!!
Thanks

**UPDATE:** Thanks for your help :) I updated the code to remove the mistakes. Now the following code works for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  (function(){
    var fb = document.createElement('iframe');
    fb.src = 'http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href='+encodeURIComponent(location.href)+'&locale=en_US&send=false&layout=button_count&width=90&show_faces=false&action=like&colorscheme=light&font=verdana&height=21';
    fb.style.cssText = 'border:none; overflow:hidden; width:90px; height:21px;';
    fb.frameBorder = '0';
    fb.scrolling = 'no';
    fb.allowTransparency = 'true';
    document.getElementById('fbabove').appendChild(fb.cloneNode(true));
    document.getElementById('fbbelow').appendChild(fb.cloneNode(true));
  })();
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Now that this has resolved the problem, you should accept whichever answer you felt answered your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not have an `id` attribute with an equal value on the same page. Fix that first, otherwise `document.getElementById()` is never going to work properly (it only ever returns one element) and `document.getElementsById()` (with an `s`) does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

The function is called `document.getElementById` and it returns a **single** element, since you can never have more than one element with the same id

So change

```
document.getElementsById('fblike')[0].appendChild(fb);
```

to

```
document.getElementById('fblike').appendChild(fb);
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, you have a type. its `getElementById`, since only one element can have an ID on any given page.

Second, since there's only one, there's no need for the `[0]`.

```
document.getElementById('fblike').appendChild(fb);
```

But, otherwise, we need more details to know if this is the only problem you have.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you want to insert two iframes into two divs, right? Here is the code which will do what you want (can't claim it is optimal since you have duplicate ids -- as people above say, you'd better make two distinct ids if possible):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function(){
    var list = document.getElementsByTagName('div'), i, fb;
    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (list[i].id == 'fblike') {
            fb = document.createElement('iframe');
            fb.src = 'http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href='+encodeURIComponent(location.href)+'&amp;locale=en_US&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=90&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font=verdana&amp;height=21';
            fb.scrolling = 'no';
            fb.frameborder = '0';
            fb.style = 'border:none; overflow:hidden; width:90px; height:21px;';
            fb.allowTransparency = 'none';
            list[i].appendChild(fb);
        }
    }
  })();
</script>
```